# memory efficient way of implementing a circular buffer using mmap

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory, mmap

I am implementing IPC using shared memory using mmap. The structure i am using for sharing is

```
struct shared{
    sem_t P;
    sem_t C;
    sem_t M;
    int prod_status;
    char** queue;
    int buffer_size;
    int queue_start;
    int queue_after_last;       //pointing to buffer index after the last element in the buffer
    int queue_count;
};
```

The size of the buffer is passed as command line argument.

```
int main(int agrc, char* argv[]){
    int N_buff=atoi(argv[1]);
    struct shared* shared_data=(struct shared*)mmap(NULL,sizeof(struct shared),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
    //printf("hello\n");
    shared_data->buffer_size=N_buff;
    shared_data->queue=(char**)mmap(NULL,sizeof(N_buff),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
    for(int i=0;i<N_buff;i++){
        shared_data->queue[i]=(char*)mmap(NULL,70*sizeof(char),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
    }
    shared_data->queue_start=0;
    shared_data->queue_after_last=0;
    shared_data->queue_count=0;
    shared_data->prod_status=1;
    sem_init(&shared_data->P,1,N_buff);
    sem_init(&shared_data->C,1,0);
    sem_init(&shared_data->M,1,1);};
```

The queue is accessed by other process. I am using the queue as pipe.
The question is, everytime I allocated memory using

```
shared_data->queue[i]=(char*)mmap(NULL,70*sizeof(char),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
```

It will allocate whole page of memory. Is there any other memory efficient way of implementing this using mmap?
I am using fork after this code to spawn a child process, so I guess I can use pointers for IPC between parent and child using this method.

Comment: I don't see how this approach can work at all.  You are storing pointers in your process-shared buffer, but the pointers of one process are not meaningful to other processes.  Not even when they point to mapped memory.

Comment: _It will allocate whole page of memory._ Shared mappings _must_ be page aligned and a multiple of the page size. There's really _no_ inefficiency here. You may have race conditions. You're not showing the _other_ client code, so it may access the area _before_ the `sem_init` calls take effect.

Comment: As John mentioned, you can't use pointers in shared memory. _Unless_ you're doing a `fork` and then calling a child function (i.e. it will inherit the parent memory mappings). If you have _two_ clients that do similar setup, as John mentioned, it _won't_ work. Better to calculate the total size of _all_ shared data and map it as one giant area. You can replace the pointers with [byte] offsets from the start of the shared area.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that I am using fork after the mentioned code. The communication takes place b/w parent and child.

Comment: Okay, then _no_ race condition on `sem_init`. So, what is the problem? In what way does the code _not_ work?

Comment: the code works perfectly fine but I guess I am occupying memory and not using it. when i use mmap, it allots me a whole page say of size 4kB of which I am using only 70B. This is repeated several times. Now say if the buffer is of size 10, then total memory allocated to process will be 40KB of which I will use only 700B. I think this would not be effiecient taking memory into consideration. Correct me if I am wrong conceptually.

Comment: Unless you're running on a microcontroller, don't worry about a few KB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had some bugs.

The second `mmap` call used `sizeof(N_buff)` [which is *always* 4] instead of: `sizeof(*shared_data->queue) * N_buff`

It is possible to do a single `mmap` for all the data [see below].

---

Here's the annotated and corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

struct shared {
    sem_t P;
    sem_t C;
    sem_t M;
    int prod_status;
    char **queue;
    int buffer_size;
    int queue_start;
    // pointing to buffer index after the last element in the buffer
    int queue_after_last;
    int queue_count;
};

int
main(int agrc, char *argv[])
{
    int N_buff = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct shared *shared_data;

    shared_data = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct shared), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    // printf("hello\n");
    shared_data->buffer_size = N_buff;
// NOTE/BUG: sizeof(N_buff) is _always_ 4
#if 0
    shared_data->queue = mmap(NULL, sizeof(N_buff), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
#else
    shared_data->queue = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*shared_data->queue) * N_buff,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
#endif
// NOTE: sizeof(char) is _always_ 1
    for (int i = 0; i < N_buff; i++) {
        shared_data->queue[i] = mmap(NULL, 70,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    }

    shared_data->queue_start = 0;
    shared_data->queue_after_last = 0;
    shared_data->queue_count = 0;
    shared_data->prod_status = 1;

    sem_init(&shared_data->P, 1, N_buff);
    sem_init(&shared_data->C, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&shared_data->M, 1, 1);
}
```

---

Here's some cleaned up code for a *single* mmap [I've compiled but *not* tested it]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define PERQUEUE 70

struct shared {
    sem_t P;
    sem_t C;
    sem_t M;
    int prod_status;
    char **queue;
    int buffer_size;
    int queue_start;
    // pointing to buffer index after the last element in the buffer
    int queue_after_last;
    int queue_count;
};

int
main(int agrc, char *argv[])
{
    int N_buff = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct shared *shared_data = NULL;
    size_t total_size = 0;

    total_size += sizeof(struct shared);
    total_size += sizeof(*shared_data->queue) * N_buff;
    total_size += sizeof(PERQUEUE * N_buff);

    void *mapbase = mmap(NULL, total_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    void *mapcur = mapbase;

    shared_data = mapcur;
    mapcur += sizeof(struct shared);

    // printf("hello\n");
    shared_data->buffer_size = N_buff;

    shared_data->queue = mapcur;
    mapcur += sizeof(*shared_data->queue) * N_buff;

    for (int i = 0; i < N_buff; i++) {
        shared_data->queue[i] = mapcur;
        mapcur += PERQUEUE;
    }

    shared_data->queue_start = 0;
    shared_data->queue_after_last = 0;
    shared_data->queue_count = 0;
    shared_data->prod_status = 1;

    sem_init(&shared_data->P, 1, N_buff);
    sem_init(&shared_data->C, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&shared_data->M, 1, 1);

    // stuff ...

    munmap(mapbase,total_size);
}
```